# Resharper warns about an unawaited async operation, but not when ConfigureAwait(false) is applied

Tags: c#, async-await, task, resharper

Sample code :

```
   _logger.WriteAsync("Instruments -> " + sb, "app")
```

[image]

Resharper legitimately warns us regarding an un-awaited asynchronous operation.

Add **.ConfigureAwait(false)** and the warning is gone. 
I don't understand why Resharper removes the warning, It is the exact same scenario, It is still an unawaited (or un continued task), It just **does not** attempt to return to the same SynchronizationContext from which it left from and it's continuation can execute on any available thread.

[image]

Any ideas ? 
Am i misunderstanding what or part of what ConfigureAwait does ?

Comment: post code instead of screen shots

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I did both. I wanted to visualize the resharper warning

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Rx. Maybe report it to JetBrains.